# Raywenderlich tutorial - Space Game

Tags: android, c++, sprite, cocos2d-x

Hello I am folowing Raywenderlich's tutorial ( http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/ ) to create Space Game in Cocos2d-x-2.2 using Eclipse for Android platform.

I have occured problem in "Adding Parallax Scrolling" part. After copy-pasting the code I can't see background sprites.

.cpp file

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
if ( !CCLayer::init() )
{
    return false;
}

CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

/////////////////////////////
_batchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("Sprites.pvr.ccz");
this->addChild(_batchNode);
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Sprites.plist");

_ship = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("SpaceFlier_sm_1.png");
CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
_ship->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width * 0.1, winSize.height * 0.5));
_batchNode->addChild(_ship, 1);
return true;

 // 1) Create the CCParallaxNode
_backgroundNode = CCParallaxNode::create();
this->addChild(_backgroundNode,-1);

// 2) Create the sprites will be added to the CCParallaxNode
_spacedust1 = CCSprite::create("bg_front_spacedust.png");
_spacedust2 = CCSprite::create("bg_front_spacedust.png");
_planetsunrise = CCSprite::create("bg_planetsunrise.png");
_galaxy = CCSprite::create("bg_galaxy.png");
_spacialanomaly = CCSprite::create("bg_spacialanomaly.png");
_spacialanomaly2 = CCSprite::create("bg_spacialanomaly2.png");

// 3) Determine relative movement speeds for space dust and background
CCPoint dustSpeed = ccp(0.1, 0.1);
CCPoint bgSpeed = ccp(0.05, 0.05);

// 4) Add children to CCParallaxNode
_backgroundNode->addChild(_spacedust1, 0, dustSpeed, ccp(0,winSize.height/2) ); 
_backgroundNode->addChild(_spacedust2, 0, dustSpeed, ccp( _spacedust1->getContentSize().width,winSize.height/2));
_backgroundNode->addChild(_galaxy, -1, bgSpeed, ccp(0, winSize.height * 0.7));
_backgroundNode->addChild(_planetsunrise, -1 , bgSpeed, ccp(600, winSize.height * 0));
_backgroundNode->addChild(_spacialanomaly, -1, bgSpeed, ccp(900, winSize.height * 0.3));
_backgroundNode->addChild(_spacialanomaly2, -1, bgSpeed, ccp(1500, winSize.height * 0.9));
this->scheduleUpdate();
}


void HelloWorld::update(float dt) {
CCPoint backgroundScrollVert = ccp(-1000, 0);
_backgroundNode->setPosition(ccpAdd(_backgroundNode->getPosition(), ccpMult(backgroundScrollVert, dt)));
}
```

.h file

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{

private:
cocos2d::CCSpriteBatchNode * _batchNode;
cocos2d::CCSprite * _ship;
cocos2d::CCParallaxNode *_backgroundNode;
cocos2d::CCSprite *_spacedust1;
cocos2d::CCSprite *_spacedust2;
cocos2d::CCSprite *_planetsunrise;
cocos2d::CCSprite *_galaxy;
cocos2d::CCSprite *_spacialanomaly;
cocos2d::CCSprite *_spacialanomaly2;

// scheduled Update
void update(float dt);
```

Any ideas where can be the error in my implementation? Resources are added propely because ship is being shown.

Comment: You dont appear to have any rendering code

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more about it? Or show me where is it in tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is :

```
return true;
```

In the middle of the code.